# code::blocks can't create files

Tags: codeblocks

I just barely installed Code::Blocks so that I can learn how to program in fortran with a real IDE (with debugging and other fun things). But I'm running into a puzzling problem while trying to get it to work--Code::Blocks seems to be unable to create any files at all.

Info: I'm running Linux Mint 17 and built Code::Blocks from source (version 13.12 for Debian, which seemed like the closest I could get). When I try to create a new project, it gives the following error for every single file in the project:

```
Warning
Couldn't save project path/filename
(Maybe the file is write-protected?)
```

This is when I run code::blocks from the terminal as a super user. When I simply run Code::Blocks without super user, I get the following:

```
Error
Couldn't create the project directory
path/
```

No idea what's going on here, and I can't find a similar question. Help?

Comment: Futile to speculate what you've done wrong. Best remove your Code::Blocks build and just install C::B 13.12 normally from Software Manager. There are no such problems with it.

Comment: While I thank you for your advice, I followed it to no avail. Code::Blocks installed normally from the package manager has the same problem. I'm wondering if it's a problem with the system, since they haven't created a version for my exact linux distribution.

Comment: Sorry that didn't work. I'm also on Linux Mint 17, with C::B 13.12 installed from Software Manager, use it constantly. Seemingly you don't have write permission to wherever the project is to be located.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer. 
**Do not create new file or new project in C**

> Try to create in other disks.
>   Folders situated in C are protected folders

and you can save your file or save as file just fine

Comment: Strangely enough, this fixed my problem. But I have seen youtube videos where they work with files on desktop (that is, in the C drive), and it works for them fine.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem but after following this below procedure I was able to run the program
Procedure:
In code-block go to the Setting, click on `Tool chain executable` then click on `auto detect`

This will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause for your problem is that you specified an invalid path to a new project when starting one.

If you see "Invalid file path" in the "Resulting filename field", you generally should not hit "Next".

Below is a screenshot showing how your dialog should look when you've filled in the file path properly:
[image: Example of a valid project file path]

In case anyone is curious, I overlooked this initially in CodeBlocks 17.2 on Windows 10 before finding this question and posting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Linux mint 19.1 with a fresh install of Code::Blocks 16.01.

I was getting the same message as below when trying to create a project and the dialog box never showed the `"invalid path"` message.

`"Couldn't create the project directory: /home/mydir/Code/CppTraining/HelloWorld/"`

I found I was able to create the path after I removed one level of subfolders. It seems code::blocks doesn't like project paths to have more than one or two levels of subfolders?

Answer (score 0):

If you're flipping back and forth from Linux to Windows, this problem may occur and it's extremely frustrating as a Linux user to debug.

Windows doesn't understand that the tilde `"~/"` means your home folder, so you actually have to type `"C:\Users\<yourusername>\<path>"`
, instead of just typing `"~/<path>"`

Hope this helps anyone that has run into this.